# GD Library - Can't output to browser (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, gd

So I have a weird issue using the GD library inside Laravel.
I can save the file correctly. Base64_encode returns the correct image.
But I cant for the life of me get it to show in the browser.
In my TestController I have the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App;
use Response;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {

      $test = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
      $background = imagecolorallocate($test, 0, 0, 0);
      imagefill($test, 0, 0, $background);
      ob_start();
      imagepng($test);
      $buffer = ob_get_contents();
      imagedestroy($test);
      ob_end_clean();

      $response = Response::make($buffer);
      $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
      return $response;
    }
}
```

That just returns a broken image.

The Console shows the correct headers. I'm pulling my hair out...

Comment: Actually I get a black square with your code .. can you give us to entire controller action code ?

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using Laravel's homestead (4.0) that comes preinstalled with GD. Will update code.

Comment: You have to mention that you are using laravel 4.0 (because I tested it on 5.2)

Comment: Laravel 5.2.29. Running on homestead 0.4. Soz typo

Comment: well .. can you remove the `$response->header(..)` and show me the response content ?

Comment: �PNG  IHDR,,�" pHYs���+IDATx���  �Om7��' Fþ(IEND�B`�

Comment: seems ok .. and everything works fine for me, I have no idea

Comment: Thanks for trying. Been struggling with this all day

Answer (score 0):

So stupid. Found a space before the php tag in my package's config file. I really can't believe it was something so stupid.